# How to highlight multiple rows when hovering over one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my table I have a some values in a column that span over multiple rows. When I hover over this value only one row is hilighted (the row containing the actual value). My question is, is there anyway to hilight the other rows when hovering on the value that spans over them ?

here is a code example :

```css
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    th, td {
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    tr:hover{background-color:#f5f5f5}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Table</h2>
    <p>Move the mouse over the table rows to see the effect.</p>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Swanson</td>
        <td rowspan="2">$300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cleveland</td>
        <td>Brown</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: So when I hover on $100, Peter and Lois rows should get highlighted ?!

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Yes, and when I hover on either Peter or Lois, $100 should be highlighted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is about when hovering $100, both Peter and Lois rows should get highlighted then you cannot do it with css alone as per my understanding. You are suppose to go for js scripts.

Check below snippet for reference. Hover on td with `rowspan`. Hope this helps.

```js
$('.hasRowSpan').hover(function(){
 $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('bg-red');
  $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass('bg-red');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

 tr:hover{background-color:red}

.bg-red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td class="hasRowSpan" rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td class="hasRowSpan" rowspan="2">$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**: You can use `nextAll()` when `rowspan` has more than 2 rows.

Find below updated snippet as per your comment.

```js
$('tr').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).find('td').hasClass('hasRowSpan')) {
    $(this).next('tr').toggleClass('bg-red');
  }
  if ($(this).prev('tr').find('td').hasClass('hasRowSpan')) {
    $(this).prev('tr').toggleClass('bg-red');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: red
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td class="hasRowSpan" rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>Rijo</td>
    <td>$500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td class="hasRowSpan" rowspan="2">$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update 1**: I just updated the script as per your comment here. **Note**: Am sure this won't be working if you have rowspan more than 2.

```js
$('.hasRowSpan').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('bg-red');
  $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass('bg-red');
});

$('tr').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).prev('tr').find('td').hasClass('hasRowSpan')) {
    $(this).prev('tr').find('td.hasRowSpan').toggleClass('bg-red');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: red
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td class="hasRowSpan" rowspan="2">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>Rijo</td>
    <td>$500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td class="hasRowSpan" rowspan="2">$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update 2**: Check above snippet, I have changed my code as per your desired output.

Comment: Thanks but it is missing a part, when I hover on either Peter or Lois, $100 should be highlighted.

Comment: Now when I hover over Peter, Lois is also highlited. That is not the desired behavior. When Peter is selected 100 should be selected and Lois unselected. When Lois is selected 100 should be selected and Peter unselected. Finally when 100 is selected Lois and Peter should be selected.

Comment: @LoayAshmawy check updated answer, which will give you desired output i hope.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in just html and cs, as long as you are fine with your rows being in different tbody tags.

```css
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    th, td {
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    tbody:hover{background-color:#f5f5f5}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Table</h2>
    <p>Move the mouse over the table rows to see the effect.</p>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Peter</td>
          <td>Griffin</td>
          <td rowspan="2">$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lois</td>
          <td>Griffin</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Joe</td>
          <td>Swanson</td>
          <td rowspan="2">$300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cleveland</td>
          <td>Brown</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```