# Table hover issue when RowSpan added

Tags: html, css

I have created application with table and which having lost of rows with row-span of 3 and when i hovering the rows its highlighting the first row not corresponding row-span rows.

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9x5gtmz/)

```css
tr:hover td{
    background: #00FF33;
}
```

```html
<table width="800" cellpadding="5" border="1">
   <tr class="head">
       <th>NO.</th>
       <th>FOOD NAME</th>
       <th>TYPE</th>
       <th>STATUS</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td rowspan='3' align='center'>1.</td>
        <td rowspan='3'>Mozarella Cheese</td>
        <td>Regular</td>        
        <td rowspan='3' align='center'>Available</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='premium'>
        <td>Premium</td>
   </tr>
      <tr class='premium'>
        <td>New</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td rowspan='3' align='center'>2.</td>
        <td rowspan='3'>Greentea Milk</td>
        <td>Regular</td>        
        <td rowspan='3' align='center'>Available</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='premium'>
        <td>Premium</td>
   </tr>
      <tr class='premium'>
        <td>New</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to hover entire 3 rows not only first row.

Current output:

[image]

This is not duplicate with [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997846/how-to-highlight-multiple-rows-when-hovering-over-one-row), since I am asking for more than 3 rows and also the solution for that question i not working and having bugs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) answered in my previous question, This can be done through small html changes.

We should use `tbody` for entire rows and can write hover function for `tbody`

```css
tbody:hover td{
background: #00FF33;
}
```

```html
<table width="800" cellpadding="5" border="1">
   <tr class="head">
   <th>NO.</th>
   <th>FOOD NAME</th>
   <th>TYPE</th>
   <th>STATUS</th>
   </tr>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan='3' align='center'>1.</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>Mozarella Cheese</td>
    <td>Regular</td>        
    <td rowspan='3' align='center'>Available</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='premium'>
    <td>Premium</td>
   </tr>
  <tr class='premium'>
    <td>New</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan='3' align='center'>2.</td>
    <td rowspan='3'>Greentea Milk</td>
    <td>Regular</td>        
    <td rowspan='3' align='center'>Available</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='premium'>
    <td>Premium</td>
   </tr>
  <tr class='premium'>
    <td>New</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5d8tpx6r)

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're searching for is sadly not possible with CSS alone, because CSS doesn't offer selectors for selecting preceding children (which you would need to highlight multiple rows). Instead, you could modify your HTML a bit using the `tbody` element to make this possible.

The `tbody` element can be used in conjunction with `thead` and `tfoot` to e.g. enable scrolling while locking the header and footer of the table in place. Also, when printing, the header and footer may get repeated on the next page, should the table span multiple pages. You can wrap your rows in `tbody` to ensure that all the rows are highlighted when you hover over them.

```css
tbody:hover td{
    background: #00FF33;
}
```

```html
<table width="800" cellpadding="5" border="1">
<tbody>
   <tr class="head">
       <th>NO.</th>
       <th>FOOD NAME</th>
       <th>TYPE</th>
       <th>STATUS</th>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
        <td rowspan='3' align='center'>1.</td>
        <td rowspan='3'>Mozarella Cheese</td>
        <td>Regular</td>        
        <td rowspan='3' align='center'>Available</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='premium'>
        <td>Premium</td>
   </tr>
      <tr class='premium'>
        <td>New</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
        <td rowspan='3' align='center'>2.</td>
        <td rowspan='3'>Greentea Milk</td>
        <td>Regular</td>        
        <td rowspan='3' align='center'>Available</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class='premium'>
        <td>Premium</td>
   </tr>
      <tr class='premium'>
        <td>New</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I found that already and I have answer the same in my own question.